# Export ChartFX7 to SVG in Java

Tags: java, xml, export, chartfx

Can anybody give an example of exporting a ChartFX7 chart to SVG?

I've tried:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    m_chart.setOutputWriter(new SvgWriter());
    m_chart.exportChart(FileFormat.EXTERNAL, baos);
```

and :

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    m_chart.setRenderFormat("SVG");
    m_chart.renderToStream();
```

But both result in a null pointer exception.

The following successfully outputs to XML:

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Debug.getInstance().createExternalFile("chart.xml"));
    m_chart.exportChart(FileFormat.XML, fos);
```

Answer (score 1):

[batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) is a libary that you can import into your java libary to convert or create svg images. I dont know chartfx7 but that is the standard way to create svg in java.